# MPRemoteCommandCenter remote command not working

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I implemented an audio player which can play audio in background. Therefore I would like to react to remote control commands like play/pause. I followed examples and created [this code (see Gist)](https://gist.github.com/funkenstrahlen/013fdcde8f698ee0c1dc#file-playerviewcontroller-swift-L49-L51).

However when I click the pause button in the control center or in the lockscreen the linked action function does not get called.

I used [this as example code](https://github.com/RIwai/SimpleLibraryMusicPlayer/blob/d325e6e713113170359e31af87e37135decdc13d/SimpleLibraryMusicPlayer/LocalMusicPlayer.swift) and of course the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW6)

- `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` done
- `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)`done
- `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` done
- Background Mode Audio/Video enabled in Info.plist
- [setting up the command actions](https://gist.github.com/funkenstrahlen/013fdcde8f698ee0c1dc#file-playerviewcontroller-swift-L49-L51) done

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you turned on background modes in your info.plist ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L70YC.png

Comment: Yes, I have enabled background modes.